# Bad Magic Number Error In Java At Command Prompt

Tags: java, ubuntu

Whenever I run the `java` command, I get the following error. How do I fix it?

> adeel@pc:~$ java
>   invalid file (bad magic number): Exec format error

Comment: Do you have the right version of Java installed? Have you manged to download and unzip the Windows version?

Comment: it was working properly. i copied few JAR files in JRE/LIB/EXT as well, could it be the reason for the error ?

Comment: How about `file $(which java)` ?

Comment: If your java is installed on a shared drive, and you are using a different operating system to access the same shared drive, then you still can have a mis-match between the executable and the operating system.  Still, the simple, common, problem is that you copied java into your computer, instead of using an installer built for your operating system.  Doing this kind of installation is risky, and often breaks.  It only can work if  both computers are very similar.  And generally, it's a bad idea to copy around the contents of a java installation, unless you're modifying the JRE.

Comment: Ah - what did you copy into `lib` and `ext`? You maybe have added binaries for incompatible operating systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution. i just setup the class path to the java installation directory and everyting started working properly.

> export PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/:$PATH

Comment: Glad to see you found your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just ignored it and program ran fine! Initially I thought it's breaking the program.